# is it possible to use back button item and left bar button items at same time in swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I want use back button item to go the stack back and a left bar button to call also the slide menu. for this a use a navigation bar , is this possible and how?

Menu button:

[image]

Back item:

[image]

Comment: Set `leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true` for `YourViewController.navigationItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can add both buttons.

In storyBoard try following:

Navigation Item -> Left Bar Button Items -> Bar Button Item -> Add both buttons.

Answer (score 1):

try like this i hope  it will work

```
let btnback = UIButton(type: .custom)
btnback.setTitle("< Back", for: .normal)
btnback.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
btnback.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.Methodname), for: .touchUpInside)
let leftItem1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnback)

let btnMenu = UIButton(type: .custom)
btnMenu.setTitle("Menu", for: .normal)
btnMenu.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
btnMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.MethodName), for: .touchUpInside)
let leftItem2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnMenu)  

self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([leftItem1,leftItem2], animated: true)
```